# Should I bother about lazy loading in a web application?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, lazy-loading

I've learned that to have a singleton lazy loading, this is the pattern to use:

```
private MyObject()
{
}

public static MyObject Instance
{
    get { return SingletonCreator.CreatorInstance; }
}

private static class SingletonCreator
{
    private static readonly MyObject _instance = new MyObject();

    public static MyObject CreatorInstance
    {
        get { return _instance; }
    }
}
```

But a more simple pattern would be:

```
private static readonly MyObject _instance = new MyObject();

private MyObject()
{
}

public static MyObject Instance
{
    get { return _instance; }
}
```

This wouldn't be lazy loading. But is this really something that I should bother about in a web application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have static methods which don't need the singleton, just including a static constructor is enough to make the class lazy. Without the static constructor it's still *mostly* lazy.

See my [singleton implementation page](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/singleton.html) for more details and options.

I'd normally the code you gave at the bottom of the question - it's lazy enough, unless you *really* don't want to initialize the singleton unless it's going to be used. (Basically with `beforefieldinit` set, the JIT will generally make sure that every type used in a method is initialized; without `beforefieldinit` it has to wait until the first actual use of the class during execution. See my [`beforefieldinit` page](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/beforefieldinit.html) for more information - but the important point is that it's still not going to initialize all singletons as soon as the assembly is loaded, or anything like that.)

Answer (score 4):

Lazy loading usually implies that you're lazily loading something from a database. What you're doing is usually called "[lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization)" (technically "lazy initialization" is a method of implementation of a lazy loading pattern).

As to your original questions: first off, you don't need a singleton. If you *still* need it, [here's](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html) how this should be done properly. Third, you don't need a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

That's all well and good, but the point of lazy loading is to avoid loading (usually unmanaged) resources (hitting a database, the filesystem, etc.) until you need to, which avoids loading them pre-emptively when you don't really need to. Use of the singleton pattern, in of itself, doesn't necessarily imply lazy-loading, since you can quite correctly create the managed instance at any point.

The lazy-loading aspect comes into play if any resources you load are only accessed when the appropriate method call is made; if, when that singleton instance is created, it does a whole bunch of database queries and stashes the result, then it's not lazy loading as far as I'm concerned.

With respect to ORM scenarios, lazy-loading usually refers directly to deferring the load of another object in a relationship until the first access, which avoids performing a second, potentially unnecessary query.

Then again, if you know you're going to be navigating that relationship in the course of your use of the object (i.e. if you've retrieved a `User` in order to list their `Posts` or something), then you probably want to instruct your ORM to load the related objects at the same time, which will usually tip it off to perform a single query with a join, rather than looping through and performing multiple queries later; in this case, you don't really want lazy-loading.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure not to confuse page load, session and application lifetime. That said, are you sure you want to use a static singleton instance? Once created, it will live until the application (the webserver) is shutdown or you run *iisreset*.

Consider caching it in `HttpContext.Current.Items` instead if you want one lazily loaded instance per page load, or perhaps in `HttpContext.Current.Session` if you want one per user.